# HPQC ALM12 - Results not being filtered on excel sheet on new version of quality center

Tags: vba, excel, alm, hp-quality-center

I have an excel sheet that was working flawlessly with hp quality center 11. When I was moved to HP QC12 , it stopped bringing the results from the filters (tree or grid) and instead it brings to my excel sheet all the requirements list for all projects.

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3DtrUkx1_yrenl2THhUUkhDWXc/view?usp=sharing)
This is the file in question that is working perfectly for alm11 and brings ALL reqs from all results on alm12. I went through the code but was not able to find solution for this issue, nor pin why is not filtering the requirements by filter.

Comment: Make sure  Macros are not Disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was ALM12 was not registered correctly. I executed the registration of tools with IE being ran as administrator as explained here
http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-and-News/Connecting-VB-Excel-macro-to-HP-ALM-QC11-52/td-p/6453694#.VZ5LmXqqr9w

Thanks to all